# Custom top border width with css

Tags: html, css, border, linear-gradients

Hello all i want to make custom top border with css but intersection lines are not straight as seen below :
[image]

And this is my css rules :

```
 border-radius: 4px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, transparent 115px, #b0b0b0 -10px);
  border-right: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
  border-left: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
  background-position: 100% 0, 100% 0, 0 100%, 0 100%;
  background-size: 100% 1px, 1px 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

The design I intend to make the question more understandable is in the picture below.

[image]

I tried some ::after , ::before solutions for that but i got same issue how can i fix this ? Thanks for answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution adds border-radius to all all corners top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right.

Instead of setting
border-radius: 4px;

simply go with specific corners for example:
border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;

would setup only bottom-left radius like here:

[image]

and reduce unwanted effect in your UI.

Comment: Thanks for the tip i don't know the border can be given to the specified corner.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `border-radius` on the bottom corners with the following.

```css
border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
```

Comment: Same as  Krzysztof Wyrzykowski solution i accepted his answer as solution thanks a lot.